# how to print output of "bit-blast" on a bit-vector expression in z3 with c++?

Tags: c++, z3, smt, bitvector

I have created a function that converts Propositional logic formulas to qdimacs. I want to convert even some bit_vector expressions to pl form  and then QDIMACS.I have this method called 'bit-blast' and an example such as :

```
std::cout << "tactic example 2\n";
    context c;
    expr x = c.real_const("x");
    expr y = c.real_const("y");
    goal g(c);
    g.add(x < 0 || x > 0);
    g.add(x == y + 1);
    g.add(y < 0);
    tactic t(c, "bit-blast");
    apply_result r = t(g);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < r.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "subgoal " << i << "\n" << r[i] << "\n";
    }
```

In this example they are using "real_const", but I need my expressions to be "bv_const". I have tried executing it with bv_const but it shows error: `Aborted(core dumped)`

I have even tried a program like this:

```
#include<z3++.h>  
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace z3;

int main()
{   context c;
    tactic t = tactic(c, "bit-blast");

    goal g(c);
    expr x = c.bv_const("x", 16);
    expr y = c.bv_const("y", 16);
   expr z = c.bv_const("z", 16);

    g.add(z = x +y);
    apply_result r = t(g);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < r.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "subgoal " << i << "\n" << r[i] << "\n";
    }

}
```

Even this give the same error: `Aborted(core dumped)`.

Is there a way where I can store the output of 'bit-blast' in an expression and print it?
Is there an example program that demonstrates my problem's solution or can you please show me how its done?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly because you used `=` instead of `==` when adding the assertion to the goal?

Comment: yes. It gave me an output. so "==" is used as an assignment operator?

Comment: No. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison, as usual in C++.

Comment: so z3 can't interpret expressions like z=x+y?

Comment: Z3's input language is not a programming language, there is no such concept as "assignment" to a variable, you can only enforce an expression to be equal to another expression, e.g. `x == y`. The `=` operator is pure C++, it overwrites the contents on the left with the contents on the right, for instance for `expr` objects.